# How to Add elements at random positions in String array from a String ArrayList. In Android Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am new to android java. And this is bugging me.
Here, my ArrayList will have only 3 strings (black, grey, white). But please answer as if it had 100 or 1000 items. Then what would be the code to do that.

```
ArrayList<String> alCelebrityAllNAMES = new ArrayList<String>();
String myArray = {"1",  "2",  "3"};

  public void regexImagesNames(){
        Pattern patternNames = Pattern.compile("/images/banners/(.*?)_234x60.gif");
        Matcher matcherNames = patternNames.matcher(fullHtmlCode);
        
        while(matcherNames.find()) {
            alCelebrityAllNAMES . add( matcherNames.group(1) ); //yields 3 words(strings)

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Get elements from the `ArrayList` and add them at random positions in the `array` or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

Solution 1, the long way...

```java
        String[] myArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
        ArrayList<String> alCelebrityAllNAMES = new ArrayList<>(myArray.length);
        ArrayList<Integer> alreadyOccupiedIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            String s = myArray[i];
            int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(myArray.length); // Getting a random index

            if(!alreadyOccupiedIndexes.contains(randomIndex))
            {
                alCelebrityAllNAMES.add(randomIndex, s);
                alreadyOccupiedIndexes.add(randomIndex);
                i++;
            }

        }
```

Solution 2:

```java
        alCelebrityAllNAMES.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray)); // Fill the arrayList with the elements of the array
        Collections.shuffle(alCelebrityAllNAMES); // shuffle the elements in it..

        // and if you need an array again:
        alCelebrityAllNAMES.toArray();
```